# creating variables from structures in matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, structure

I have the following example which expresses the type of problem that I'm trying to solve:

```
clear all
textdata = {'DateTime','St','uSt','Ln','W'};
data = rand(365,4);
Final = struct('data',data,'textdata',{textdata})
clear textdata data
```

From this, Final.data contains values which correspond to the headings in Final.textdata excluding the first ('DateTime') thus Final.data(:,1) corresponds to the heading 'St'... and so on. What I'm trying to do is to create a variable in the workspace for each of these vectors. So, I would have a variable for St, uSt, Ln, and W in the workspace with the corresponding values given in Final.data.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to use the `assignin` function, like so (edit: just like macduff suggested 10 minutes ago):

```
%Starting with a Final structure containing the data, like this
Final.textdata = {'DateTime','St','uSt','Ln','W'};
Final.data = rand(365,4);

for ix = 1:4
    assignin('base',Final.textdata{ix+1}, Final.data(:,ix));
end
```

However, I strongly discourage using dynamic variable names to encode data like this.  Code that starts this way usually ends up as spaghetti code full of long string concatenations and `eval` statements.    Better is to use a structure, like this

```
for ix = 1:4
    dataValues(Final.textdata{ix+1}) = Final.data(:,ix);
end
```

Or, to get the same result in a single line:

```
dataValues = cell2struct(num2cell(Final.data,1), Final.textdata(2:end),2)
```

Comment: great method, but as stated above the data is originally in a structure so how would I apply this to my data (see amended question), i.e. how do I get to the different cells in textdata?

Answer (score 3):

Will this solve your problem:

```
    for ii=2:length( textdata )
      assignin('base',Final.textdata{ii},Final.data(:,ii-1));
    end
```

Let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: It is kind of what I was looking for, but the data that I have is stored in a structure, similar to 'Final' above (question amended).